# Invoke Firebase method getInstance error. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Tags: java, android

Android studio show this what is the problem?
i include this file compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'`
but it also shows this. whats the matter?

> 08-12 08:56:52.773 22268-22319/? W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method
>   getInstance error.
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.orangehostbd.bpl-1/base.apk",

Comment: what are you using firebase for notifications or storage and please post your logcat error code

Comment: If you are using Firebase for notifications then to initialize fire base you have to do something like this    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);      But do not forget to use services and files related to Firebase services

Comment: i am not  using firebase for notifications. i just use admob ad. ad perfectly show but log cat show this massage.

Comment: //Add this in OnCreate of Activity to initialize the ad
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "< your-ad-unit-Id >");    try this

Comment: Are you seeing this with release and debug builds?  If release only, are you using ProGuard?

Comment: I have the same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Google Play Service. Here is the link to Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/appMeasurement/google-admob-ads-sdk/9Cukd02En9o/ELCZfzjUCQAJ It should be fixed if one of the next release

Comment: 5 years and 11 versions later, here I am with the same log warning

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today, and adding this to the Proguard/R8 rules fixed it:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement {public *; }
```